# Стандарт кодирования Zend Framework

Tags: ооп, стандарт, php, zend-framework

В стандарте кодирования Zend Framework использование public свойств считается дурным тоном. Правильно использовать private свойства и public методы для работы с ними.

```
class MyClass
{
    public  $email;
    private $_name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }
}

// Использование

$my = new MyClass();
$my->email = 'mail@mail.ru';   // дурной тон
$my->setName('Вася');          // правильно
```

Почему работа с public свойствами не приветствуется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ибо [инкапсуляция](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Инкапсуляция_(программирование)). А вообще почитайте «Совершенный код» Макконнелла, книга неплохо отвечает на вопрос «что такое хорошо и что такое плохо».

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы всегда можно было отследить изменение переменной в ОДНОМ месте. В случае чего - запретить. С пабликом, у вас присваивания будут валяться по всему коду, я уже молчу про то, что иногда таким образом очень легко напакостить. Например, присвоив в свойство неочищенную инфу из POST или GET.
Лично я использую вообще магические методы `__set`, `__get`, чтобы не заморачиваться.

Comment: А как входящие данные обрабатываете? switchem?

Мне тоже, безусловно, импонируют `__get` и `__set` методы, но ИМХО с их использованием, мягко говоря, код читабельнее не становится.

Эх, если бы в php были бы реализованы геттеры и сеттеры по-нормальному :(

Answer (score 0):

Иногда можно использовать `public` свойства, для классов, не находящихся в "ядре", особенно если вы понимаете - что указанное `public` свойство можно будет установить откуда угодно для объекта. Когда get* и set* методов много - это тоже плохо. На помощь приходит реализация свойств на PHP `__set` и `__get` .

Вы спрашивали в коментах:

> А как входящие данные обрабатываете? switchem?

Нет, например создаёте в классе внутренний массив:

```
protected $_properties = [];
```

Обработчики, например такие:

```
public function __get($property)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($property, $this->_properties)) {
        throw new Exception("Specified property \"$property\" is not in the row");
    }
    return $this->_properties[$property];
}

public function __set($property, $value)
{
    if ($this->isReadonly($property)){
        throw new Exception("Specified property \"$property\" is read only.");
    }
    /* ... тут может быть ваша логика проверки на запись ...*/
    $this->_properties[$property] = $value;
    return $this;
}
```

Так работает многое в самом Zend - [например их реализация ActiveRecord](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/zf/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php) . Поясню - ActiveRecord - объектное представления ряда в БД. Например очень удобно делать так:

```
$row->title = "Some title";
$row->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$row->save();
```

**Мораль** - get* и set* методы хороши только в малом количестве. Их использование не динамично, они вредят обозримости класса (который эти методы содержит), особенно если класс нарушает SRP. Для гибкого читаемого кода - реализуйте свойства с `__set` и `__get` .